# Android MediaRecorder - Screen recording video gets corrupted

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

We are using the screen recording functionality of Android's [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) APIs.

On Some devices, the recorder video gets corrupted. But, it is not consistent.

Sometimes it works on the same device as well. I have tried changing the video encoder from     H264 to the default one. But that didn't work.

Has anyone faced a similar issue previously and can help us?